# DirectShow RTSP SourceFilter with MPEG-4 Video Stream 

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, h.264, rtsp, mpeg-4

I create  a simple direct show source filter using FFmpeg.I read rtp packets from RTSP source and give them to decoder. **It works for h264 stream.**

```
MyRtspSourceFilter[H264 Stream] ---> h264 Decoder --> Video Renderer
```

**The bad news is that it does not work for MPEG-4.**  I can able to connect my rtsp source filter with MPEG-Decoder. I got no exception but video renderer does not show anything. **Actually just show one frame then nothing** [just stop]... Decoders and Renderers are 3rd party so i can not debug them.

```
MyRtspSourceFilter[MP4 Stream] ---> MPEG-4 Decoder --> Video Renderer
```

I can able to get rtp packets from MPEG-4 RTSP Source using FFmpeg sucessfully.There is no problem with it.

> It seems that i have not set something(?) in my Rtsps Source
>   Filter which is not necessary for H264 stream but may be important for
>   MPEG-4 stream

**What may cause this h264 stream and MPEG-4 stream difference in a direct show rtsp source filter?** Any ideas.

**More Info:**

-- First i try some other rtsp source filters for MPEG-4 Stream...Although my rtsp source is same i see different subtypes in their pin connections.

-- Secondly i realy get suspicious if the source is really MPEG-4  SO i check with FFmpeg...FFmpeg gives the source codec id as  "CODEC_ID_MPEG4".

**Update:** 
**[ Hack ]**

I just  set m_bmpInfo.biCompression = DWORD('xvid') it just worked fine...But it is static. **How to dynamically get/determine**  this value using ffmpeg or other ways...

Comment: Do you reassemble packets correctly? MPEG4 and H264 packetizations are not same! Do you use `0x000001` code for each reassembled frame before you send it to decoder? Are your media sample timings correct?

Comment: I understand that MPEG4 and H264 packetizations are not same! FFmpeg do  packetizations for me ..   But i really wanted to know how to add 0x000001 code for each reassembled frame  by myself...What is its algorithm-pattern?

Comment: Actually you answer it from my different question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-in Thanks....I will try

Comment: Oh sorry didn't notice that this was also your question.

Answer (score 1):

I am on the RTSP-server side, different use case with required by-frame conversions

```
MP4 file ---> MPEG-4 Decoder --> H264 Encoder -->  RTSP Stream
```

Will deploy [libav](https://libav.org/download/), which is kernel of ffmpeg.

**EDIT:**
With H264 encoded video layer, the video just needs to be remuxed from
length-prefixed file format "AVCC" to byte stream format according to some "Annex B" of the MPEG-4 specification. libav provides required bit-stream filter "h264_mp4toannexb"

```
MP4 file ---> h264_mp4toannexb_bsf -->  RTSP Stream
```

Now, for decoding RTSP:

Video and Audio come in separate channels. Parsing and decoding the H264 stream is done here: [my basic h264 decoder using libav](https://github.com/DaWelter/h264decoder/commit/be980ebf1ece512041f071c5d2bd7172b9d6e0c6)

Audio is a different thing:
[RTP Transport](https://www.cimarronsystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/RTP-Protocol-Transport-of-H.264-Video-and-AAC-Audio-v1_2.pdf) suggests, that AAC frames are encapsulated in ADTS, where RTSP players like VLC expect plane AAC and accordingly available RTSP server implementations [AACSource::HandleFrame()](https://github.com/PHZ76/RtspServer/blob/master/src/xop/AACSource.cpp) pinch the ADTS header off.

Another different thing is "time stamps and RTP":
VLC does not support compensation of time offsets between audio and video. Nearly every RTSP producer or consumer has constraints or non-documented assumptions for a time offset; you might consider an additional delay pipe to compensate the offset of an RTSP source.