# MPEG4 out of Raw RTP Payload

Tags: c++, rtsp, rtp, mpeg

Okay I got the following problem:

1. I have an IP Camera which is able to stream MPEG4 data over RTP
2. I am able to connect to this camera via RTSP
3. I can receive the raw RTP data.

So what problems do I have now?

**1. Extract Data**

What is the data I actually want? I know that I have to trunkate the `RTP Header` - but is there anything else I need to cut from the `RTP` packets?

**2. Packetization Mode**

I read that I should expect a field `Packetization Mode` in my `SDP`- well it's not there. Does that mean I have to assume some kind of standard packetization mode?

**3. Depacketization**

If I got it right I need to buffer all incoming frames with the `Marker Bit = false` until I get a frame with `Marker Bit = true` to get a complete `MPEG4 Frame`.  What exactly do I have to understand by `MPEG4 Frame`? Keyframe + data until next keyframe?

**4. Decode**

Do I have the decode the data any further then? In other threads I saw that people used another decoder - but what is there left to decode? I mean the camera should send the data already `MPEG4` coded?

**5. Libraries**

If I really need to decode the data, are there any open libraries I could use for that? Or maybe there is even a library which has some functions where I can just dump my RTP data and then magic happens and I get my mp4. ( But I assume there will be nothing like that .. )

*Note:* Everything I want to do should be part of my own application, meaning for example, I can't use an external software to parse the data.

Well long story short - I'd really need some kind of step by step explanation for this to do. I know this is a broad question but I don't know any further. I also looked into the `RFCs`, but I couldnt extract much information out of them.

Also I already looked up these two Questions:

[How to process raw UDP packets so that they can be decoded by a decoder filter in a directshow source filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-i)

[MPEG4 extract from RTP payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887922/mpeg4-extract-from-rtp-payload)

But also the long answer from the first question could not make everything clear to me.

**UPDATE:** Well I informed a bit further and now I don't know where to look anymore. It seems that all the packetization stuff etc. is actually not needed for my purpose. I also recorded a stream with [openRTSP](http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/). When I open those files in a Hex-Editor I see that there are 16 Bytes which I can't identify, followed by the `config` part of the `SDP`. Then the frame starts with the usual `00 00 01 B6`. Also `oprenRTSP` adds some kind of tail to the `MP4` - well I actually don't know what I need and whats just some "extra" stuff which isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

> I know that I have to trunkate the RTP Header - but is there anything
> else I need to cut from the RTP packets?

RTP packet might have stuff data from a file format (such as MP4) or it could have directly based on [RFC 3640](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3640) or something similar. You need to find that out.

> What exactly do I have to understand by MPEG4 Frame? Keyframe + data
> until next keyframe? Do I have the decode the data any further then?
> In other threads I saw that people used another decoder - but what is
> there left to decode? I mean the camera should send the data already
> MPEG4 coded?

You should explore basics of MPEG compression to appreciate this fully. The depacketization only give you a string of bits. This is compressed data. You need to uncompress it (decode it) to see it on the screen.

> are there any open libraries I could use for that?

try [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) or [MPEG4IP](http://mpeg4ip.sourceforge.net)