# h264 global header

Tags: c, ffmpeg, h.264, libx264

I need to process an incoming h264 stream from an external server.

This stream is composed by h264 frames with sps / pps information.

I need to "strip" this information out and pass the data along to the receiver.

How can I do this ?

Comment: So you need to append some stuff? Because there is no such well known thing as "global headers" in H.264, perhaps you need to improve the question.

Comment: When encoding with x264 there is an option "b_repeat_headers" which mean we want to send sps / pps information along with every keyframe. ffmpeg call "global header" when b_repeat_headers is set to false.

Comment: This is what I mean "improve the question". `b_repeat_headers` has nothing to do with `H.264`. It is specific to x264 or something else, so you need to explain what you are trying to reach. I suppose you want to parse out SPS/PPS NAL units and duplicate them by re-inserting with every I-Frame. This is what you need to add to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

depends on the protocol the remote server use.

check this link if it's RTP:

[process raw udp packets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-i)