# How to dump the H264/RTP stream to a file without losing time info?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, rtp, x264

I coded an application to receive RTP packets via TCP (no packets are lost) from a hardware camera and dump its H264 packets to a file so I could play the video using MPlayer or VLC. This is already working and I pretty much did the steps described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-i). The commands to play the video are `mplayer -fps 24 -demuxer h264es foobar.h264` and `vlc foobar.h264`.

The issue is now when I play the video. The camera changes the FPS frequently and because I drop the RTP info when writing the H264 file, the timestamp of each frame is lost. My question is: what do I have to do to fix the frame frequency? Should I create empty/blank P-frames (if that is possible)? If so, how would I do it?

Any solution using Linux compatible tools or libraries (like ffmpeg, libx264, libavcodec) using shell, C/C++ or Python is very much welcome.

PS: I have almost no experience with video encoding and RTP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no timing information in a raw h.264 stream. The stream needs to be put into a container such as MP4 or FLV where you can tag each frame with a PTS/DTS.