# DVR video-stream parse

Tags: video, stream, h.264, decoder

I'm reading a video stream from a DVR that says h264 encoded. I thought I would find a standard packetized H264 FRAGMENT as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-i) but it looks like there is some kind of proprietary rule in this stream.

How to get the h264 fragments or any other useful information from this stream?

The stream has a header that starts with 0x31 (4x) and after some bytes that I don't know what they mean, the server sends slices of h264 raw data (`0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01`). I put this data in a raw.h264 file and I converted it to an mp4 movie using FFmpeg. I got a very bad quality video with green screen at most part of the time.

```
0000   31 31 31 31 74 00 00 00 01 00 00 0a ff ff ff ff  1111t...........
0010   04 00 00 00 64 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 03 00 00 00  ....d...........
0020   28 00 00 00 60 01 00 00 f0 00 00 00 c0 d8 d6 01  (... ...........
0030   00 00 00 00 20 06 48 01 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00  .... .H.....@...
0040   00 00 00 00 bb 40 c9 8e 1f 0b 05 00 95 b6 26 bf  .....@........&.
0050   26 00 00 00 28 00 00 00 60 01 00 00 f0 00 00 00  &...(... .......
0060   01 00 10 00 48 32 36 34 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ....H264........
0070   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00              ............

...

0000   31 31 31 31 34 00 00 00 04 00 00 09 ff ff ff ff  11114...........
0010   76 2f 73 64 24 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 ff ff 00 00  v/sd$...........
0020   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 34 20 00 00  ............4 ..
0030   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 31 31 31 31  ............1111
0040   1c 00 00 00 02 00 00 09 ff ff ff ff 10 00 00 00  ................
0050   0c 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 3c 20 00 00 00 00 00 00  ........< ......
0060   31 31 31 31 18 05 00 00 01 00 00 0a ff ff ff ff  1111............
0070   04 00 00 00 08 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  ................
0080   cb 04 00 00 60 01 00 00 f0 00 00 00 48 30 0a 42  .... .......H0.B
0090   00 00 00 00 20 01 74 03 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00  .... .t.....@...
00a0   00 00 00 00 07 50 e5 8e 1f 0b 05 00 0f b7 42 bf  .....P........B.
00b0   26 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 61 e1 60 91 42 bc 9d 7e  &.......a. .B..~
00c0   08 fd 7b e5 f6 0f c5 f3 03 5f b0 1f 97 af c4 f7  ..{......_......
00d0   f6 13 e2 f5 f9 0a f8 43 5f b3 db f8 25 f3 53 55  .......C_...%.SU
00e0   af 84 74 97 d9 d2 fd d2 eb 9b af c9 af e2 fd 7a  ..t............z
00f0   6f 84 f5 d5 77 cb db f9 6b 5a e2 3a 2f 75 c4 74  o...w...kZ.:/u.t
0100   f5 fd f3 9a f8 ff 7e db 1e be 13 f6 5b 7f 26 5d  ......~.....[.&]
0110   fc 27 d8 15 03 fd 8a e5 a5 24 a9 78 4f 7e 6c fc  .'.......$.xO~l.
0120   4f ab ac 9b e3 ae cd 2a 7e f5 ec 21 d2 9a 1b 5a  O......*~..!...Z
0130   af 9b d7 df af 82 4f 4b be 5d f2 77 5e 4d 6b 8c  ......OK.].w^Mk.
0140   be 6a 23 46 be 12 f5 a5 45 e3 bb 6c b4 da 3e 7f  .j#F....E..l..>.
0150   85 2d 3e ef cd f4 af af 8c f3 e6 c9 bd 2d dc 3d  .->..........-.=
0160   c6 f1 96 7a 55 96 5c 4b 6d fe 5e f5 c5 eb 4d f5  ...zU.\Km.^...M.
0170   d4 7d 7d a6 9e b7 f3 5b 4f 25 e4 cd 4b fe b5 aa  .}}....[O%..K...
0180   9e b9 34 52 67 82 5f 68 c4 1f ef be ba 13 fe eb  ..4Rg._h........
0190   ea 83 b3 79 b1 f0 45 7f d5 af 07 1f 2d 4c 4f f3  ...y..E.....-LO.
01a0   50 3f a8 43 d2 31 2f 47 fc 21 da 6a 94 a4 5a fe  P?.C.1/G.!.j..Z.
01b0   24 bb 06 78 7c 48 bd 83 74 98 3a 5f 17 c8 4a 62  $..x|H..t.:_..Jb
01c0   3f c7 f6 bd a4 5f c2 5d ad ff 05 bd 1d de b9 72  ?...._.].......r
01d0   4d e6 25 e4 ef f0 c5 9b 3d 59 eb d3 ff 09 53 af  M.%.....=Y....S.
01e0   6b b8 2e f7 46 d7 17 52 e9 7e 10 a5 d2 e9 3f e0  k...F..R.~....?.
01f0   8e be be 6a 69 e4 e3 b6 fd a9 98 3f 37 d7 24 d9  ...ji......?7.$.
0200   7f 8f cf 99 f3 e3 d9 2e f6 e2 28 d1 f3 12 d7 2e  ..........(.....
0210   97 e2 2b 3e da fe fb a3 f1 f9 f2 fb 33 65 9f a9  ..+>........3e..
0220   a9 25 f8 63 d5 9f 54 ff f8 28 d6 eb e2 f8 47 a5  .%.c..T..(....G.
0230   e9 6c c3 79 6f 1d d7 cf 77 96 0f c9 7f ab f4 7a  .l.yo...w......z
0240   82 3e fc be 6e bf 04 36 ab aa 78 53 ec 4e ff 5f  .>..n..6..xS.N._
0250   37 ba b8 cd fe d5 76 b7 f5 15 da bb a0 6d 4b f3  7.....v......mK.
0260   fe 5b 47 c1 8c f7 9c dd 2f 93 a4 62 3e 23 a5 d6  .[G...../..b>#..
0270   4e 4b ff 74 99 fe 22 79 7d 1e b6 31 cc 31 8c 10  NK.t.."y}..1.1..
0280   a7 c2 fd 04 a9 75 6b ff 85 3a f4 ad 7a f1 77 05  .....uk..:..z.w.
0290   54 be aa fe 2d e2 ae df e8 67 a9 2f eb e7 ff 1f  T...-....g./....
02a0   e7 da ea a3 df bd 46 56 fa 5a 51 d1 ae 5f 36 78  ......FV.ZQ.._6x
02b0   ee ac fa 79 69 f1 9a 0a 89 91 11 bd d8 0b b2 6f  ...yi..........o
02c0   e1 0b 74 f5 b7 55 35 71 c4 10 f1 90 41 30 c6 af  ..t..U5q....A0..
02d0   19 2e 25 5e ce 9e 4a e7 38 54 9e 10 e7 8a 5a 25  ..%^..J.8T....Z%
02e0   6a 97 51 d8 c6 df 71 07 ab 37 f7 2f 11 c6 5a 34  j.Q...q..7./..Z4
02f0   bf 88 f6 0f b5 40 e0 46 10 f3 12 e8 fb 0b 89 17  .....@.F........
0300   ed 5a fc 5f 26 f6 3f 97 ce 41 7c 54 f3 ad 11 4c  .Z._&.?..A|T...L
0310   68 16 a1 1e 5c 2f bc da 96 bd c7 6a 45 3d f3 13  h...\/.....jE=..
0320   6a af c6 6b 3e 39 a3 96 56 a5 a5 e3 4c 7c 75 dd  j..k>9..V...L|u.
0330   b7 f4 9b 4e 9f 85 28 1b 52 fc a3 ec 9e 08 57 cf  ...N..(.R.....W.
0340   9f 5f 1d 3b cb fb c8 35 93 d7 da f1 36 8f 8d 6c  ._.;...5....6..l
0350   1d 2f 8b b5 4b 26 67 ef 7d 5c 46 8f af e2 3b 34  ./..K&g.}\F...;4
0360   0d 99 b5 03 80 fe 3e 8e 82 67 d8 36 92 da f1 dd  ......>..g.6....
0370   03 46 c1 b5 60 d7 f9 ab ee 09 9a 15 e6 da 5f 8c  .F.. ........._.
0380   d0 2f ba 2e d4 b4 f8 43 a3 66 bc 32 f7 2c 97 19  ./.....C.f.2.,..
0390   b4 8a 40 57 af 65 f8 43 1a 7c 86 1b 27 47 ec 1d  ..@W.e.C.|..'G..
03a0   26 fe 3e 93 eb ec 1f e3 36 be b7 de 97 c7 fb 4d  &.>.....6......M
03b0   51 eb f6 ef fc d6 9a fc bd 24 92 e3 66 ba d5 3f  Q........$..f..?
03c0   37 af 05 3f 1d d0 24 d7 a1 d3 f8 2e d8 5b 86 97  7..?..$......[..
03d0   79 db e3 2d 3f a3 3d 37 a0 2e be 33 af 58 f8 c2  y..-?.=7...3.X..
03e0   89 99 ee 8b 71 dc 69 a3 61 18 6b a7 af 83 0e 86  ....q.i.a.k.....
03f0   c1 ce 5f 5b 7f f8 43 26 7b 6d ec 11 6f c7 f9 37  .._[..C&{m..o..7
0400   b5 47 f8 23 a0 b6 a0 fb ef f2 ef ae 4e 97 c9 da  .G.#........N...
0410   f8 2e af b5 d7 cb b4 5c 89 d6 ea 26 9d 6b fc be  .......\...&.k..
0420   c6 b8 ac b6 82 80 ab f8 47 3d a5 9c d0 cc b3 7f  ........G=......
0430   bf c6 48 33 0b 4f da 6b 3d fe 2e 82 61 5a 6a ff  ..H3.O.k=...aZj.
0440   09 7b eb f0 5b d2 2d da e0 d1 b8 db f4 b6 e9 a7  .{..[.-.........
0450   d9 b0 75 fe 9f 84 ba 4e 8a df c9 6b be 4e ff 75  ..u....N...k.N.u
0460   5f cb 7f a8 9e ba dd 72 f5 ae 2b bf bf bd 7e c9  _......r..+...~.
0470   6e 9d 72 65 85 fc 4f 4f a5 f8 c9 4c ac 3a d3 30  n.re..OO...L.:.0
0480   92 89 4f fe 69 fe 10 ae 8a 4f e1 d6 ab f8 cc 92  ..O.i....O......
0490   67 d7 df b4 fe fa fc 92 19 1d 23 b2 be fe c2 f1  g.........#.....
04a0   74 90 2f 60 fe 08 7d b7 3e 12 96 54 b7 fc bd 57  t./ ..}.>..T...W
04b0   c1 75 7e ba f7 7c 21 bf 5f 5b d9 b6 fe 8d af e5  .u~..|!._[......
04c0   eb f1 54 05 87 f2 b9 20 c7 e3 36 9f 8d a3 e9 eb  ..T.... ..6.....
04d0   bc dd 17 8e a4 a8 9f 45 5b fa 11 6f bc c4 67 df  .......E[..o..g.
04e0   c5 52 e7 cf e1 2d af 0d a8 7e 2f b2 f4 07 e0 ae  .R...-...~/.....
04f0   ad 25 be ff be 11 a4 c0 49 fa 0b b7 e1 1d b5 60  .%......I...... 
0500   e7 cf 98 7c e1 1f 19 da 8c cd 6c 10 16 a9 7a d1  ...|......l...z.
0510   f8 4f 69 a7 d1 35 e2 25 c0 df 91 37 fb f9 69 ff  .Oi..5.%...7..i.
0520   36 b4 02 f2 5f f9 bd 81 f9 bd 25 1d 7b fe 5d 7f  6..._.....%.{.].
0530   09 fa 7a 7f 24 8a bf cb 45 1b 10 ba e5 93 5a fc  ..z.$...E.....Z.
0540   bd fe fd 83 31 bf 13 d8 f4 5f 84 67 58 e4 3d 7b  ....1...._.gX.={
0550   fe 10 ec 1d 03 ef fd ed 58 17 84 e8 09 2e 83 fc  ........X.......
0560   4f a7 b5 f0 9f 9d 46 ff 08 d8 fe ce ff c5 72 7c  O.....F.......r|
0570   c0 87 f0 51 a0 ef b2 f7 cb ef e0 9f b5 eb d8 d7                                               ...Q............


0000   31 31 31 31 9c 08 00 00 01 00 00 0a ff ff ff ff  1111............
0010   04 00 00 00 8c 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  ................
0020   4e 08 00 00 60 01 00 00 f0 00 00 00 48 d0 0a 42  N... .......H..B
0030   00 00 00 00 20 01 9c 03 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00  .... .......@...
0040   00 00 00 00 af db e7 8e 1f 0b 05 00 b7 42 45 bf  .............BE.
0050   26 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 61 e1 83 14 2b cb ce a3  &.......a...+...
0060   e2 fd 01 71 a2 c3 e1 ce c3 40 db 6f ff 08 6b ae  ...q.....@.o..k.
0070   c0 b4 6c 17 8a af d0 5f 19 69 76 ba ac 70 72 9a  ..l...._.iv..pr.
0080   9b f8 4a cf d7 f0 c5 56 75 bb 4b db ff 17 d0 04  ..J....Vu.K.....
0090   ca 34 88 08 07 c1 67 ad 68 05 36 75 f1 be 6a 69  .4....g.h.6u..ji
00a0   2d 9a f1 96 cd 6d ff e3 7d d2 b6 9e ac eb c5 a7  -....m..}.......
00b0   ff 82 ba 36 a8 fb 5b 6c 8d 55 41 5e bd 4b 6c f8  ...6..[l.UA^.Kl.
00c0   f5 8f e5 70 a5 7d 7b 5f 35 2b e1 1a fa e4 ff c2  ...p.}{_5+......
00d0   15 f9 3d 77 f1 5e fd fd d7 f9 2e ff 88 f6 3d 7f  ..=w.^........=.
00e0   13 92 2f b1 a6 c5 f0 85 13 e9 74 bf 88 ef 63 d1  ../.......t...c.
00f0   78 fc a3 fd e7 49 3a 3f c2 7f 6e 82 a2 f1 dd 8d  x....I:?..n.....
0100   d8 0b d1 fe 33 6a d7 64 8f b5 fc 67 6b 63 f7 bd  ....3j.d...gkc..
0110   bf 82 5b 1f da 6a be 32 50 45 0b e9 a3 96 4d 6f  ..[..j.2PE....Mo
0120   fc 6e b7 6a f7 e9 25 49 69 ff e0 b3 cd 8e f5 79  .n.j..%Ii......y
0130   fb e3 3b e9 ef 93 1f 52 5a 85 39 66 c1 fd ba 5e  ..;....RZ.9f...^
0140   ff 68 45 c5 d6 82 e3 bf 75 3c de df 8f bf 93 ed  .hE.....u<......
0150   51 fc 77 dd 92 f6 ff 09 fb ab df c4 7a 5d 6f 83  Q.w.........z]o.
0160   90 47 ed 57 c4 db bd bf e5 e9 dd 7e e6 a7 5c 4e  .G.W.......~..\N
0170   bf 5f 25 3f e1 cf 6f 2f 6f fc 66 7b b9 a2 94 23  ._%?..o/o.f{...#
0180   65 2d 1b a4 9c 2f 0a 74 6a dd da 42 fd b3 6c b6  e-.../.tj..B..l.
0190   ab e1 08 d7 9b 4f 35 09 3d 84 8e be 33 33 14 74  .....O5.=...33.t
01a0   a8 11 b2 fa 4d a4 3d 8f 7c 74 b3 7a 59 32 d3 71  ....M.=.|t.zY2.q
01b0   d9 e6 f8 c7 84 7c d6 86 6b a4 93 bb f7 aa d3 88  .....|..k.......
01c0   18 2a 6e 6a 3d f4 bc 4e d3 f5 f4 fd 57 5a fb 99  .*nj=..N....WZ..
01d0   29 f0 99 89 e4 a0 8c 77 f0 45 e4 cc be 33 bd 9e  )......w.E...3..
01e0   eb ed fe 5e bf 0d 5f f5 3f fe eb 6b ea fe c4 75  ...^.._.?..k...u
01f0   bf 5c 46 bd 3f df 6b d5 72 d5 2f c2 9a 77 df 90  .\F.?.k.r./..w..
0200   bf a0 38 be 1f f4 46 ec d8 0b b0 7a ec 2f ea 18  ..8...F....z./..
0210   e3 4d 0e c4 0f 50 d7 96 9f fe 2e f8 d1 a3 46 8f  .M...P........F.
0220   58 62 6b 07 fc 21 cd 94 bd 51 fc 67 5e ba 2d 03  Xbk..!...Q.g^.-.
0230   fe 32 ad 57 a0 69 6d b5 4c f4 dc 6f b4 df bd 1b  .2.W.im.L..o....
0240   cb a3 3c bd bf f1 fe d7 5d fa 8c eb df bd 53 b3  ..<.....].....S.
0250   dc 67 4b 44 91 7a 9a 9b a8 d2 3f 8e b5 ec ab 5b  .gKD.z....?....[
0260   5f 08 75 d7 c6 95 99 b8 20 f4 e9 47 59 f4 eb db  _.u..... ..GY...
0270   ff 06 1d d3 5e bb 7f f1 9a fd 47 2a fe ff 0f da  ....^.....G*....
0280   b0 e4 97 4f ae 9f fc da eb 97 d7 c7 54 63 4d 54  ...O........TcMT
0290   ae 7b ba 9f ea 3b d9 e6 22 8d 7e ef 45 f8 fe 7c  .{...;..".~.E..|
02a0   bb f3 87 d1 a0 7e 14 df a5 f2 62 4f db e2 24 c4  .....~....bO..$.
02b0   0b 1e 2e 7f 88 85 6c fe d3 4a df fb f1 1a 33 c7  ......l..J....3.
02c0   a3 bf 88 df 7e 4c d4 3d d2 1c 89 de c9 a3 ee a9  ....~L.=........
02d0   a7 fe e3 ef e4 b2 d3 21 c3 9c ae e1 bb 22 4b 5a  .......!....."KZ
02e0   7f ea 36 81 fd f6 a7 c6 af ca f6 ff c2 fa 3f a2  ..6...........?.
02f0   4c bf b5 a8 ca 3b 07 eb 78 e6 51 76 bc 27 6b f6  L....;..x.Qv.'k.
0300   66 cf 05 3d a7 af 5f 2f 8c a4 ba 5d 6f 6b 67 e1  f..=.._/...]okg.
0310   0e b9 69 e4 c5 f0 59 e9 96 99 f3 66 5f 0e 7a 6b  ..i...Y....f_.zk
0320   db ff 2d bf e0 ae 6f f1 8a ee a7 65 af 66 b4 b7  ..-...o....e.f..
0330   dc 67 a5 69 03 a5 fa 5b 8d 90 83 b2 9f 11 3b 32  .g.i...[......;2
0340   53 7d 74 ff e1 1e a6 c7 25 ea 74 cc f5 32 e1 a1  S}t.....%.t..2..
0350   e2 79 b1 4f 8f c6 b0 a4 ba f0 47 d3 b6 fc be fd  .y.O......G.....
0360   82 cd 7e 5c c6 73 fb d1 3c e4 1e 84 73 90 68 fa  ..~\.s..<...s.h.
0370   83 3d 71 17 e7 d1 fe 22 8d 83 da aa 7c f1 16 9f  .=q...."....|...
0380   d1 b0 7d c1 2d 24 ac cc 43 c8 d3 6e 63 e1 0a 09  ..}.-$..C..nc...
0390   83 ab 5d 7f 8f ed 16 f7 49 0f f8 76 94 d7 ed 74  ..].....I..v...t
03a0   96 9f fe 5b 7e 5f fc 64 76 9e 97 e6 fb 85 27 85  ...[~_.dv.....'.
03b0   81 b4 9c b8 37 84 92 dd 93 2d cb 92 14 ad 02 a7  ....7....-......
03c0   27 bc 56 91 85 5e cc f6 39 49 ba 0f 8c c7 6c 7b  '.V..^..9I....l{
03d0   ca b8 6d 9b fa 9f 59 ef fe 14 dd da c3 6a ba a8  ..m...Y......j..
03e0   e4 62 8f 37 34 4c 72 f0 f8 cb 0d 2d 06 8a 71 d0  .b.74Lr....-..q.
03f0   fa b6 e6 90 65 b2 18 cb 71 76 b3 c6 4b 84 38 10  ....e...qv..K.8.
0400   65 d2 57 40 d6 36 8c c6 4d 0b c7 c5 7c 58 ea dc  e.W@.6..M...|X..
0410   67 43 9a fc 8f 6e ec 9f f0 53 60 c7 d8 5a 30 e3  gC...n...S ..Z0.
0420   c7 fd 5d 4e be fa f0 70 f5 f5 88 f8 8b 5a 36 0f  ..]N...p.....Z6.
0430   f8 c9 af 28 c7 bb c3 e3 ac af bf 17 f1 a2 fd 9e  ...(............
0440   91 af c5 ed 33 f6 0b cb 47 7d 46 62 ee d1 48 d4  ....3...G}Fb..H.
0450   ed 50 3f 04 9e 93 ef 15 17 9b fa ed 03 e5 15 49  .P?............I
0460   a3 52 a3 51 80 80 cc c7 8c 95 fc 98 37 9c 59 ae  .R.Q........7.Y.
0470   90 e8 41 16 9b 09 91 52 f8 52 d4 48 7a f1 51 98  ..A....R.R.Hz.Q.
0480   87 4e a7 cd be 14 be dd 46 ba 80 8b 85 b8 e9 b7  .N......F.......
0490   3d 8c 23 e8 d4 e7 c6 71 c7 c6 14 68 2f e2 f1 c2  =.#....q...h/...
04a0   10 71 96 d8 a7 5f 8c a1 73 f6 92 4c 0c b6 e9 f4  .q..._..s..L....
04b0   8f 08 52 be 32 cd a6 2f 37 b8 8c 8f 4e 76 d5 aa  ..R.2../7...Nv..
04c0   86 79 ff 08 47 86 1a fc 97 e5 d3 6a 7b ef e6 b1  .y..G......j{...
04d0   a0 ff 2d 2f 5f bf f9 bd 57 27 bf bd af cd ab fc  ..-/_...W'......
04e0   23 b0 7a fb bf c4 46 6f 42 d9 30 37 7f 8e bf e9  #.z...FoB.07....
04f0   20 6a a4 a7 2d 3f 1f b3 9c 82 d9 6b f9 88 de 41   j..-?.....k...A
0500   e2 75 6d 76 f6 27 42 b5 4d 36 1a ca 67 c6 69 3b  .umv.'B.M6..g.i;
0510   49 0d e0 83 ea 2e e6 a1 39 71 6e 8c fe 18 cf 9d  I.......9qn.....
0520   a4 55 6e 9f fc 9b 0b f1 94 b1 fb 06 58 5e e6 5d  .Un.........X^.]
0530   a6 69 7e 33 1b 25 b7 dd 28 d9 ea 94 06 db 54 43  .i~3.%..(.....TC
0540   d0 8f 0a 47 62 78 d0 4b 6b bf 1b 41 0d 65 b8 99  ...Gbx.Kk..A.e..
0550   78 27 96 91 2a bc 99 d7 c6 52 3d b3 a7 96 85 c7  x'..*....R=.....
0560   fd 9f 8c e9 76 9a b5 5a 3f c2 1e e9 6d 2d a7 f0  ....v..Z?...m-..
0570   8e fa 32 e2 5f 6b c1 35 ed 76 9e af 9b 7d e4 fb  ..2._k.5.v...}..
0580   ef f5 7f 89 b7 6e de bd 0a d0 fb 6a 9f 87 7a 11  .....n.....j..z.
0590   47 e2 54 ff d4 17 4b 56 b6 ff f0 af 40 f8 7e 7d  G.T...KV....@.~}
05a0   2a a3 2a 52 08 65 6f ff 8c c2 1a 09 5b ab 3f 94  *.*R.eo.....[.?.
05b0   2d a0 bf 1b                                      -...


0000   7a fb 8c 95 9e 35 a4 e6 9a 31 db a7 ff 1f c6 42  z....5...1.....B
0010   17 2f 35 d0 1f bd 7e 1e f4 22 00 00 e8 e9 93 8f  ./5...~.."......
0020   ca 6d 7c 1f a7 f8 dc 63 cc ba 9d ee 88 c9 2d e0  .m|....c......-.
0030   1d 0b af f4 fc 15 67 91 23 42 2c f6 08 10 93 41  ......g.#B,....A
0040   a5 aa b8 99 78 9d 1f 45 1c c6 aa 11 bf a3 f5 ea  ....x..E........
0050   33 4b 5f bf bf 82 9b 57 77 7f ad 7c 16 6d 51 bf  3K_....Ww..|.mQ.
0060   a5 d7 c2 3d e9 7e fe 33 5a af be fa ea 12 ed 5f  ...=.~.3Z......_
0070   f9 7b df 1f ae b5 af d4 45 7f 5e dc df fc b5 fe  .{......E.^.....
0080   3f d5 26 45 57 8d 9f 6e 53 f1 94 b5 98 da ee 95  ?.&EW..nS.......
0090   10 e2 f6 be 3a fa 2e 3d 17 36 bf 8c a5 fd 46 49  ....:..=.6....FI
00a0   fc 4c 26 92 46 97 8e da ca 62 c2 a0 35 fe 14 ca  .L&.F....b..5...
00b0   34 89 f1 28 81 d3 38 20 d8 22 e5 4e f4 bb 8f 0a  4..(..8 .".N....
00c0   6d d7 17 fd c7 9a 37 d8 75 08 53 38 b2 6e 39 b1  m.....7.u.S8.n9.
00d0   f0 a6 c8 b1 6d 52 e8 ea d0 53 76 66 dd c9 e9 72  ....mR...Svf...r
00e0   0f d7 5b 57 fe 2e 93 7a ff 13 a5 6b 5f 8c ef d2  ..[W...z...k_...
00f0   af eb b8 9e bd 7a 82 3e d3 d7 c5 57 d7 f1 9a 7a  .....z.>...W...z
0100   e5 63 5b ef dc 7e ba f7 fd fa 09 fa eb ec 7e be  .c[..~........~.
0110   b6 3e b8 2a f5 0e 24 a3 80 5b 6c 91 37 a1 94 7e  .>.*..$..[l.7..~
0120   37 97 be 9d 91 72 63 55 d4 eb 5a ee 47 5b 8f 71  7....rcU..Z.G[.q
0130   e9 71 52 66 74 95 38 83 c0 be 78 cd 7e 32 9d c3  .qRft.8...x.~2..
0140   2f 24 c1 fd 9e 08 77 23 b9 f8 29 e6 f4 74 0b d2  /$....w#..)..t..
0150   af 86 b6 b5 d3 ff 8e df 60 e9 5a cd 9e 32 ca 62  ........ .Z..2.b
0160   2c 18 c8 50 ff 5d 7f 05 7d 05 1a 0b 75 53 f6 b2  ,..P.]..}...uS..
0170   f8 eb 2e ff b0 5e 3e fc 70 71 eb 8e 17 3f c1 47  .....^>.pq...?.G
0180   6d 75 d7 91 d7 f8 47 b5 df d1 7a c5 f0 86 d7 da  mu....G...z.....
0190   6b fb ab bf 70 5b ba eb 76 f8 9e c7 df b6 6e bd  k...p[..v.....n.
01a0   c9 a6 bf 2f 5f 82 79 d4 b7 29 0f 24 c0 f1 c0 e0  .../_.y..).$....
01b0   5b e3 e6 c3 41 13 cd a3 2f 75 23 b2 26 4c d3 3d  [...A.../u#.&L.=
01c0   8c 90 c4 e4 91 5f 4b 54 34 8e 2c d2 f9 36 0d 49  ....._KT4.,..6.I
01d0   9d 8a e3 dd 1b f2 2f c2 94 4c 91 fb 3d 02 1a 0a  ....../..L..=...
01e0   8f f1 7c 67 26 59 d0 3e c2 43 cd bf 19 96 16 ae  ..|g&Y.>.C......
01f0   d7 71 e0 00 9b 50 7c 65 cb 74 90 26 93 ec 2e 60  .q...P|e.t.&... 
0200   00 12 80 01 f1 96 54 16 56 29 4b ca 35 42 64 92  ......T.V)K.5Bd.
0210   01 06 9a f7 c2 9b 3f 29 2d 76 06 bf d5 77 f8 ca  ......?)-v...w..
0220   6d 14 61 fa f0 9f 00 16 78 5b 40 26 1f 8c c6 4d  m.a.....x[@&...M
0230   56 17 3e a7 54 2f 5f 84 2b c9 f4 5b fc 23 7e f2  V.>.T/_.+..[.#~.
0240   c6 bf c6 6b 77 bf 0c c3 fe e9 7e 13 f5 b0 4e 4e  ...kw.....~...NN
0250   b6 e7 63 47 55 2e b6 fd cd f5 f1 fe ad ad ce c4  ..cGU...........
0260   bc df c2 18 3d 12 67 07 c3 a0 eb fc 67 6b b2 e2  ....=.g.....gk..
0270   d5 7f 6b d8 ce fe 6b 49 ad fb 5e 13 e6 cb ff 1f  ..k...kI..^.....
0280   b6 ac 03 ba 0b 4b f8 7e 67 34 22 fd 3e 3e 70 eb  .....K.~g4".>>p.
0290   f5 fc 16 ee 31 af 64 ae df 0a 5c c1 05 17 05 ce  ....1.d...\.....
02a0   c2 03 4d e8 fd be 3a 84 9e fe 55 0f fc 7e 9f 9c  ..M...:...U..~..
02b0   37 7f e1 2f 1f 08 24 10 37 3d c7 f1 93 80 b1 ce  7../..$.7=......
02c0   ae e4 44 4a b0 7b 06 d6 3f 09 d3 f4 eb f1 fd f6  ..DJ.{..?.......
02d0   02 df f8 cb c2 02 19 83 7a c4 cd bf 86 f4 7c a8  ........z.....|.
02e0   4f 91 f8 ba db 43 e4 fe 2b 68 9f ba 66 6c 13 43                                                  O....C..+h..fl.C


0000   31 31 31 31 b0 04 00 00 01 00 00 0a ff ff ff ff  1111............
0010   04 00 00 00 a0 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00  ................
0020   62 04 00 00 60 01 00 00 f0 00 00 00 48 c0 0b 42  b... .......H..B
0030   00 00 00 00 20 01 d8 03 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 00  .... .......@...
0040   00 00 00 00 2d 68 ea 8e 1f 0b 05 00 35 cf 47 bf  ....-h......5.G.
0050   26 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 61 e1 a3 14 28 bc 2f 6b  &.......a...(./k
0060   eb 5b 5f f8 ea ef bf a0 4b 8b f4 b6 01 f9 af a3  .[_.....K.......
0070   f0 49 a3 df eb 87 c3 f6 7e df af 2f a7 fc 46 b4  .I......~../..F.
0080   68 fa e5 d5 ab ee ff cb ef e6 cd 4d 3e 0f 6b 96  h..........M>.k.
0090   c4 49 7e fd 8f c2 7a 2e 9f e4 b1 db ae 12 a1 f6  .I~...z.........
00a0   5f de bf 89 e9 d8 07 27 f0 45 61 fe f8 9a 1f c7  _......'.Ea.....
00b0   57 f1 96 d7 df ad 24 a4 cf 19 eb 7a 97 3d 5d af  W.....$....z.=].
00c0   51 5b f5 6b e3 2e c1 a5 4f ed ed 7d 82 6e 94 d0  Q[.k....O..}.n..
00d0   49 b6 bb eb df 52 df 04 75 f5 f3 57 fb f5 5a 9f  I....R..u..W..Z.
00e0   bd 2d 70 e5 a4 ed af 4f fc 77 4d ef 4b 4a 8f c6  .-p....O.wM.KJ..
00f0   7a 63 cb c6 d1 f2 95 ab 55 f0 9d a7 7a 5a f8 77  zc......U...zZ.w
0100   59 f3 4c de fc ab ff c2 14 bd e9 2a f7 c1 5d ff  Y.L........*..].
0110   4d 25 5f 7c 56 d1 7d c9 97 f1 3d fe ef 05 9f 72  M%_|V.}...=....r
0120   67 ea 4e 6e b5 5f 64 df f5 af 93 4a 63 1f 04 f5  g.Nn._d....Jc...
0130   fd f2 f8 21 eb d7 c9 bf ee 6c fe ad 7c 97 4f 55  ...!.....l..|.OU
0140   df af 7c 4f a4 ac 1e b9 6c 1f f1 7e d5 2d 70 95  ..|O....l..~.-p.
0150   7d 83 d7 08 76 af d9 e9 6e 13 f6 9f f8 42 be 5a  }...v...n....B.Z
0160   55 e9 16 5e f3 66 b9 6b d7 06 1e ef eb b5 fc b0  U..^.f.k........
0170   55 df 4a b4 b9 cf 85 fb ef af 6f fc 10 f7 c5 f3  U.J.......o.....
0180   53 ed e1 0f c7 75 af 57 37 d7 11 69 aa 6b fc 55  S....u.W7..i.k.U
0190   df ed 79 a8 fb ee 08 9b 58 2f 7e 7d fa 5e ee ec  ..y.....X/~}.^..
01a0   fe 2f 40 f2 5f f7 e5 df 17 9b 27 c4 7f e1 3b 5f  ./@._.....'...;_
01b0   b5 e0 bf a0 77 f2 e9 ff de 9f e7 aa 7f fc 75 55  ....w.........uU
01c0   3a fd cb 9e 0a 34 b4 5d fe 08 b4 b7 fa f5 77 57  :....4.]......wW
01d0   fc d5 df c2 1e 8f 7f 35 f8 8d f2 17 eb e2 f9 31  .......5.......1
01e0   6f 22 39 7e 7f 72 cf 6f 17 cb cd 1a e5 f7 ec 9e  o"9~.r.o........
01f0   8f df 60 d1 93 93 60 ff 25 83 fe 09 6c bd 2f 2f  .. ... .%...l.//
0200   8f a5 fd 93 5f c7 fb ec ec 1f f0 97 2e 77 f8 47  ...._........w.G
0210   d5 ae d7 bc 57 e3 34 f4 67 35 f5 df e3 f9 90 da  ....W.4.g5......
0220   5e bf 8c a7 7c 61 79 a5 6e e8 ff 05 5f 67 ba 6b  ^...|ay.n..._g.k
0230   eb e1 0d 83 e8 ba 56 bc 21 2e b7 b2 6a de 5c f8  ......V.!...j.\.
0240   42 e9 18 7e 12 1b 26 8e 20 a3 60 de 72 af 08 d2  B..~..&. . .r...
0250   55 f2 9a 6b fc 4e 49 6c 39 f2 6b fd fa fb e8 e9  U..k.NIl9.k.....
0260   44 66 d9 ef 5f 04 94 fc 5f 19 da b3 6e 95 83 a4  Df.._..._...n...
0270   a9 7e 22 d4 f9 98 60 d7 c6 6b f1 a1 02 ec 05 ab  .~"... ..k......
0280   f1 9e 1a 5d 1b e9 bf f1 93 86 03 c2 b0 a9 d7 bf  ...]............
0290   f1 96 07 1a f2 0c 12 76 90 d3 be c1 bf c2 12 31  .......v.......1
02a0   98 bc d2 fa 5e fa 82 7f 79 52 f5 27 57 ae 4d 7f  ....^...yR.'W.M.
02b0   7b ef 84 f7 65 bf e4 ed 3f 93 db f2 53 fe 08 a8  {...e...?...S...
02c0   79 8c e5 f0 59 6b a2 6e 6a 35 bb 57 5e f8 ff 60  y...Yk.nj5.W^.. 
02d0   3a 6c 05 e4 cf 08 7b 1d 2a 09 07 b7 e3 f7 35 35  :l....{.*.....55
02e0   bf 41 bf 82 7b a5 bd 70 7c 15 7b 59 69 af 96 83  .A..{..p|.{Yi...
02f0   1c 7f 4b de fd 06 38 be be fe 2f 2e 49 9a fd 7a  ..K...8.../.I..z
0300   7b d6 8d ad 7b 27 5f 84 b6 b6 95 37 f2 50 1d 7e  {...{'_....7.P.~
0310   2b b4 82 af e2 ed 7e 8b c7 73 52 c2 4f 67 fc 27  +.....~..sR.Og.'
0320   62 fa fc 7d e8 0e cf ec 1f c2 7e 9f 7f 13 bf da  b..}......~.....
0330   5c 65 7e fd fc d4 f8 4e ff bb df cd d2 f9 3b d5  \e~....N......;.
0340   6b 7f 7d 7d af 57 04 5b 4c 0c c8 a5 f1 9d b6 52  k.}}.W.[L......R
0350   91 d1 97 5b 84 6c da f8 5a 81 7b 4d 6b 6f ff 04  ...[.l..Z.{Mko..
0360   9a 5e 5f 17 ec f5 f8 ce c1 ae c1 e8 3d 23 11 fc  .^_.........=#..
0370   23 ed f4 0d 3d 8f c7 6d 2e e9 3a 2f e6 f7 f0 45  #...=..m..:/...E
0380   da f7 cb bb 55 c2 7d f7 fc b7 fe 5f 7f 57 ee 3f  ....U.}...._.W.?
0390   a9 33 bb ff 35 ff fc d4 ff 8f eb d3 ad 6b 8a d3  .3..5........k..
03a0   f9 c7 fc 23 53 57 bf cb 9e 3b 17 61 76 f4 1f c2  ...#SW...;.av...
03b0   14 fa 48 bd 7e 3e 41 fa 7e fb 5a e7 ae df fc db  ..H.~>A.~.Z.....
03c0   07 f8 af 49 2f e2 7d bb fe b5 f7 7e 5e b2 f9 75  ...I/.}....~^..u
03d0   bf fc 96 f5 e4 7a eb 82 7b 5d be c7 df 19 59 f3  .....z..{]....Y.
03e0   9a 9a f6 92 45 9f 84 29 2e bf b2 f9 32 e7 b8 ad  ....E..)....2...
03f0   bd 34 bf 27 a2 f1 7b df 6b e2 76 be df 82 9d f2  .4.'..{.k.v.....
0400   4b d8 36 2b 0f 15 d1 fb 03 f1 9d aa 6f b5 f9 6f  K.6+........o..o
0410   c9 7b fc 65 d8 34 4f df 60 f4 bf 17 ef b0 be 5f  .{.e.4O. ......_
0420   63 f0 49 af 5f 37 a1 2c ea fe 15 be 4a b1 7e 3b  c.I._7.,....J.~;
0430   b0 2f 7e 83 f1 19 65 c3 af 50 9f 79 68 bf 42 fd  ./~...e..P.yh.B.
0440   15 3f cd 7f e0 8e 9f 6f 88 ef b0 2f cd 7f e6 b2  .?.....o.../....
0450   fe 23 41 7a 7f 36 ff 8a a2 a0 3a f5 c5 60 00 f1  .#Az.6....:.. ..
0460   b8 4c a5 b1 9b d9 ff 78 00 03 26 20 82 30 ac eb  .L.....x..& .0..
0470   16 79 34 3f ff f8 12 19 11 c5 6c 43 5e d4 a7 ff  .y4?......lC^...
0480   43 97 e2 33 5c 64 10 40 03 06 a4 49 4f ed e3 30  C..3\d.@...IO..0
0490   01 f0 00 b6 31 08 e9 7c 17 f6 74 7e fd fd 3d 01  ....1..|..t~..=.
04a0   8e 9a e4 2a d1 96 d8 6d e4 c7 dd bf fa f8 23 ae  ...*...m......#.
04b0   f1 7c 57 69 6f 58 a6 2f                          .|WioX./
```

Answer (score 0):

The DVR stream is composed by a header that starts with `0x31 0x31 0x31 0x31`, In order to extract the video data you have to parse the stream looking for the header and after that for the SPS, PPS and Video Frame (most of them will have only the video frame). The necessary data to build your `.h264` file will always start with `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01` byte sequence.