# Receiving RTP packets after RTSP setup

Tags: python, sockets, udp, rtsp, rtp

I'm trying to stream RTP packets from an IP camera using Python.

I am able to send the describe, setup & play commands using RTSP protocol, however, I am unable to start streaming the actual videostream using RTP.

Here is the code:

```
import socket 

def printrec(recst):
  recs=recst.split('\r\n')
  for rec in recs:
    print rec

dest="DESCRIBE rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.74 RTSP/1.0\r\nCSeq: 2\r\nUser-Agent: python\r\nAccept: application/sdp\r\n\r\n"

setu="SETUP rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.74/trackID=1 RTSP/1.0\r\nCSeq: 3\r\nUser-Agent: python\r\nTransport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=60784-60785\r\n\r\n"

play="PLAY rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.74/ RTSP/1.0\r\nCSeq: 5\r\nUser-Agent: python\r\nSession: SESID\r\nRange: npt=0.000-\r\n\r\n"

# .. here SESID will be substituted with the session id that SETUP returns us ..

ip="192.168.1.74"
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip,554))

s.send(dest)
recst=s.recv(4096)
printrec(recst)

# etc. then the same for the strins "setu" and "play"

....
```

Setup replies me:

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Session:       1117448817;timeout=60
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=60784-60785;server_port=8214-8215;ssrc=40d35c30;mode="play"
Date:  Mon, Jan 19 2015 11:10:08 GMT
```

So we have the client ports 60784 and 60785 and the server ports 8214 and 8215.

Next, play replies me:

```
RTSP/1.0 200 OK 
CSeq: 5
Session:       1117448817
RTP-Info: url=rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.74/trackID=1;seq=3539;    rtptime=16026930
Date:  Mon, Jan 19 2015 11:10:08 GMT
```

Next, what am I supposed to do in order to start receiving RTP packets?
Open an UDP socket as follow .. ?

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((ip, serverport))
sock.recv(4096)
```

But I get nothing .. (it stalls)

Excuse me my poor knowledge of sockets..!

Comment: Shouldn't you be binding client_port?

Answer (score 56):

So,

After heavy sessions of googling and wireshark-analysis, I came up with the right solutions.

I am posting the resulting demo-code here .. I thought it might be usefull for the community.

If you ever wanted to read ip-cams with python and dump the H264 stream into an edible file, this is the thing you're looking for.

Enjoy!

```
"""
A demo python code that ..

1) Connects to an IP cam with RTSP
2) Draws RTP/NAL/H264 packets from the camera
3) Writes them to a file that can be read with any stock video player (say, mplayer, vlc & other ffmpeg based video-players)

Done for educative/demonstrative purposes, not for efficiency..!

written 2015 by Sampsa Riikonen.
"""

import socket
import re
import bitstring # if you don't have this from your linux distro, install with "pip install bitstring"

# ************************ FOR QUICK-TESTING EDIT THIS AREA *********************************************************
ip="192.168.1.74" # IP address of your cam
adr="rtsp://admin:12345@192.168.1.74" # username, passwd, etc.
clientports=[60784,60785] # the client ports we are going to use for receiving video
fname="stream.h264" # filename for dumping the stream
rn=5000 # receive this many packets
# After running this program, you can try your file defined in fname with "vlc fname" or "mplayer fname" from the command line
# you might also want to install h264bitstream to analyze your h264 file
# *******************************************************************************************************************

dest="DESCRIBE "+adr+" RTSP/1.0\r\nCSeq: 2\r\nUser-Agent: python\r\nAccept: application/sdp\r\n\r\n"
setu="SETUP "+adr+"/trackID=1 RTSP/1.0\r\nCSeq: 3\r\nUser-Agent: python\r\nTransport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port="+str(clientports[0])+"-"+str(clientports[1])+"\r\n\r\n"
play="PLAY "+adr+" RTSP/1.0\r\nCSeq: 5\r\nUser-Agent: python\r\nSession: SESID\r\nRange: npt=0.000-\r\n\r\n"

# File organized as follows:
# 1) Strings manipulation routines
# 2) RTP stream handling routine
# 3) Main program



# *** (1) First, some string searching/manipulation for handling the rtsp strings ***

def getPorts(searchst,st):
  """ Searching port numbers from rtsp strings using regular expressions
  """
  pat=re.compile(searchst+"=\d*-\d*")
  pat2=re.compile('\d+')
  mstring=pat.findall(st)[0] # matched string .. "client_port=1000-1001"
  nums=pat2.findall(mstring)
  numas=[]
  for num in nums:
    numas.append(int(num))
  return numas


def getLength(st):
  """ Searching "content-length" from rtsp strings using regular expressions
  """
  pat=re.compile("Content-Length: \d*")
  pat2=re.compile('\d+')
  mstring=pat.findall(st)[0] # matched string.. "Content-Length: 614"
  num=int(pat2.findall(mstring)[0])
  return num


def printrec(recst):
  """ Pretty-printing rtsp strings
  """
  recs=recst.split('\r\n')
  for rec in recs:
    print rec


def sessionid(recst):
  """ Search session id from rtsp strings
  """
  recs=recst.split('\r\n')
  for rec in recs:
    ss=rec.split()
    # print ">",ss
    if (ss[0].strip()=="Session:"):
      return int(ss[1].split(";")[0].strip())


def setsesid(recst,idn):
  """ Sets session id in an rtsp string
  """
  return recst.replace("SESID",str(idn))



# ********* (2) The routine for handling the RTP stream ***********

def digestpacket(st):
  """ This routine takes a UDP packet, i.e. a string of bytes and ..
  (a) strips off the RTP header
  (b) adds NAL "stamps" to the packets, so that they are recognized as NAL's
  (c) Concantenates frames
  (d) Returns a packet that can be written to disk as such and that is recognized by stock media players as h264 stream
  """
  startbytes="\x00\x00\x00\x01" # this is the sequence of four bytes that identifies a NAL packet.. must be in front of every NAL packet.

  bt=bitstring.BitArray(bytes=st) # turn the whole string-of-bytes packet into a string of bits.  Very unefficient, but hey, this is only for demoing.
  lc=12 # bytecounter
  bc=12*8 # bitcounter

  version=bt[0:2].uint # version
  p=bt[3] # P
  x=bt[4] # X
  cc=bt[4:8].uint # CC
  m=bt[9] # M
  pt=bt[9:16].uint # PT
  sn=bt[16:32].uint # sequence number
  timestamp=bt[32:64].uint # timestamp
  ssrc=bt[64:96].uint # ssrc identifier
  # The header format can be found from:
  # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol

  lc=12 # so, we have red twelve bytes
  bc=12*8 # .. and that many bits

  print "version, p, x, cc, m, pt",version,p,x,cc,m,pt
  print "sequence number, timestamp",sn,timestamp
  print "sync. source identifier",ssrc

  # st=f.read(4*cc) # csrc identifiers, 32 bits (4 bytes) each
  cids=[]
  for i in range(cc):
    cids.append(bt[bc:bc+32].uint)
    bc+=32; lc+=4;
  print "csrc identifiers:",cids

  if (x):
    # this section haven't been tested.. might fail
    hid=bt[bc:bc+16].uint
    bc+=16; lc+=2;

    hlen=bt[bc:bc+16].uint
    bc+=16; lc+=2;

    print "ext. header id, header len",hid,hlen

    hst=bt[bc:bc+32*hlen]
    bc+=32*hlen; lc+=4*hlen;


  # OK, now we enter the NAL packet, as described here:
  # 
  # https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6184#section-1.3
  #
  # Some quotes from that document:
  #
  """
  5.3. NAL Unit Header Usage


  The structure and semantics of the NAL unit header were introduced in
  Section 1.3.  For convenience, the format of the NAL unit header is
  reprinted below:

      +---------------+
      |0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
      |F|NRI|  Type   |
      +---------------+

  This section specifies the semantics of F and NRI according to this
  specification.

  """
  """
  Table 3.  Summary of allowed NAL unit types for each packetization
                mode (yes = allowed, no = disallowed, ig = ignore)

      Payload Packet    Single NAL    Non-Interleaved    Interleaved
      Type    Type      Unit Mode           Mode             Mode
      -------------------------------------------------------------
      0      reserved      ig               ig               ig
      1-23   NAL unit     yes              yes               no
      24     STAP-A        no              yes               no
      25     STAP-B        no               no              yes
      26     MTAP16        no               no              yes
      27     MTAP24        no               no              yes
      28     FU-A          no              yes              yes
      29     FU-B          no               no              yes
      30-31  reserved      ig               ig               ig
  """
  # This was also very usefull:
  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665217/how-to-process-raw-udp-packets-so-that-they-can-be-decoded-by-a-decoder-filter-i
  # A quote from that:
  """
  First byte:  [ 3 NAL UNIT BITS | 5 FRAGMENT TYPE BITS] 
  Second byte: [ START BIT | RESERVED BIT | END BIT | 5 NAL UNIT BITS] 
  Other bytes: [... VIDEO FRAGMENT DATA...]
  """

  fb=bt[bc] # i.e. "F"
  nri=bt[bc+1:bc+3].uint # "NRI"
  nlu0=bt[bc:bc+3] # "3 NAL UNIT BITS" (i.e. [F | NRI])
  typ=bt[bc+3:bc+8].uint # "Type"
  print "F, NRI, Type :", fb, nri, typ
  print "first three bits together :",bt[bc:bc+3]

  if (typ==7 or typ==8):
    # this means we have either an SPS or a PPS packet
    # they have the meta-info about resolution, etc.
    # more reading for example here:
    # http://www.cardinalpeak.com/blog/the-h-264-sequence-parameter-set/
    if (typ==7):
      print ">>>>> SPS packet"
    else:
      print ">>>>> PPS packet"
    return startbytes+st[lc:]
    # .. notice here that we include the NAL starting sequence "startbytes" and the "First byte"

  bc+=8; lc+=1; # let's go to "Second byte"
  # ********* WE ARE AT THE "Second byte" ************
  # The "Type" here is most likely 28, i.e. "FU-A"
  start=bt[bc] # start bit
  end=bt[bc+2] # end bit
  nlu1=bt[bc+3:bc+8] # 5 nal unit bits

  if (start): # OK, this is a first fragment in a movie frame
    print ">>> first fragment found"
    nlu=nlu0+nlu1 # Create "[3 NAL UNIT BITS | 5 NAL UNIT BITS]"
    head=startbytes+nlu.bytes # .. add the NAL starting sequence
    lc+=1 # We skip the "Second byte"
  if (start==False and end==False): # intermediate fragment in a sequence, just dump "VIDEO FRAGMENT DATA"
    head=""
    lc+=1 # We skip the "Second byte"
  elif (end==True): # last fragment in a sequence, just dump "VIDEO FRAGMENT DATA"
    head=""
    print "<<<< last fragment found"
    lc+=1 # We skip the "Second byte"

  if (typ==28): # This code only handles "Type" = 28, i.e. "FU-A"
    return head+st[lc:]
  else:
    raise(Exception,"unknown frame type for this piece of s***")



# *********** (3) THE MAIN PROGRAM STARTS HERE ****************

# Create an TCP socket for RTSP communication
# further reading: 
# https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/sockets.html
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((ip,554)) # RTSP should peek out from port 554

print
print "*** SENDING DESCRIBE ***"
print
s.send(dest)
recst=s.recv(4096)
print
print "*** GOT ****"
print
printrec(recst)

print
print "*** SENDING SETUP ***"
print
s.send(setu)
recst=s.recv(4096)
print
print "*** GOT ****"
print
printrec(recst)
idn=sessionid(recst)

serverports=getPorts("server_port",recst)
clientports=getPorts("client_port",recst)
print "****"
print "ip,serverports",ip,serverports
print "****"

s1=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s1.bind(("", clientports[0])) # we open a port that is visible to the whole internet (the empty string "" takes care of that)
s1.settimeout(5) # if the socket is dead for 5 s., its thrown into trash
# further reading:
# https://wiki.python.org/moin/UdpCommunication

# Now our port is open for receiving shitloads of videodata.  Give the camera the PLAY command..
print
print "*** SENDING PLAY ***"
print
play=setsesid(play,idn)
s.send(play)
recst=s.recv(4096)
print
print "*** GOT ****"
print
printrec(recst)
print
print
print "** STRIPPING RTP INFO AND DUMPING INTO FILE **"
f=open(fname,'w')
for i in range(rn):
  print
  print
  recst=s1.recv(4096)
  print "read",len(recst),"bytes"
  st=digestpacket(recst)
  print "dumping",len(st),"bytes"
  f.write(st)
f.close()

# Before closing the sockets, we should give the "TEARDOWN" command via RTSP, but I am feeling lazy today (after googling, wireshark-analyzing, among other-things).
s.close()
s1.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for posting a follow-up for your problem. If I wanted to be able to access the NTP timestamp, which I believe is included in a header from the sender (if I understand it correctly), would it be possible with a bit of modification to this code or am I misunderstanding the flow?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there's yet another UDP port (in addition to the UDP ports where you get the media), that's using the RTCP protocol, which gives you the offsets that you must use to correct for the NTP timestamps coming in the RTP packets.  .. but said that, it doesn't make any sense to go that far with the above python code snippet.  I'd suggest using libValkka instead (see the updated answer below).  The transport his handled by live555 that takes care of all these issues and you can also get your frames into python

Comment: @ElSampsa how do i get the NTP timestamps in libValkka?

Comment: maybe you should ask that in libValkka github issues?  :)

Comment: Hello how disable timeout camera in request? And in which type of request should I set the timeout? And how? because in response setup request timeout default is the 60s. Do I have to give the timeout as a URL parameter?. thanks @El Sampsa

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using now:

```
import time
from valkka.core import *

live_out_filter = InfoFrameFilter("live_out_filter")
livethread = LiveThread("livethread")
ctx = LiveConnectionContext(LiveConnectionType_rtsp, "rtsp://user:password@192.168.x.x", 1, live_out_filter)
livethread.startCall()
livethread.registerStreamCall(ctx)
livethread.playStreamCall(ctx)
# stream frames for 10 seconds
# livethread is written is cpp and is running in the background
# we could do whatever other task here.  In this example, just sleep
time.sleep(10)
livethread.stopCall()
print("bye")
```

See more at https://elsampsa.github.io/valkka-examples/